# JAVA gui: array being modified unexpectedly

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface

Problem with gui application where array of objects been passed to the constructor, however when new round is initialised, it modifies somehow const_AnimalFamily array, where I want to make it unchanged at each round, however final cannot be used here.  Other class initialises this class, however here is my main. Any suggestions? Thank you!

why its been changed each time I modify animalFamily, const_AnimalFamily being affected even if I did not do anything to it?

Comment: For a better chance of getting a response, I suggest you narrow down your codes to relevant areas that might be causing the problem.

Comment: If you really want to ensure an array doesn't get changed, consider using Guava's ImmutableList instead.

Comment: @isim some people were complaining that here are not enough details..@dnault I want to know why its been changed each time I modify animalFamily, const_AnimalFamily being affected even if I did not do anything to it?

Comment: @ProgLearner Who are those some people? To quote the SO help page: *...But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But don't just copy in your entire program!...* http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is much too large for being analyzed. But as you declared two arrays assigning their references to fields, I simply assume that you once assign one field to the other.

And indeed you have the line:

```
animalFamily = const_AnimalFamily;
```

I futher assume that you want to *copy* all contents from `const_AnimalFamily` to `animalFamily`. But this is not the case.

In Java, such assignments simply assign the *reference* to the variable (or the field). That means, both fields now refer to the *same* array. Actually, the array that was referred to by the field `const_AnimalFamily` before, is now obsolete and cannot be used anymore.

If you now access some array content, for example

```
animalFamily[0] = ...
```

and afterards read from

```
... = const_AnimalFamily[0]
```

you will get the same object that you previously wrote into the array.

Solution: If you really wanted to copy the array, do the following:

```
animalFamily = Arrays.copyOf(const_AnimalFamily, const_AnimalFamily.length);
```

Another (better) solution would be to use collections.

Comment: Copying arrays worked indeed and the problem was with objects linked to the same reference. Thank you for your clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's right as per your observation "Problem with gui application where array of objects been passed to the constructor, however when new round is initialised, it modifies somehow const_AnimalFamily array, where I want to make it unchanged at each round".

See this your code:

```
 public AnimalGUI(Animal[] temp) {

    System.out.println("INSIDE CONSTRUCTOR");

    const_AnimalFamily = temp;
```

You are changing the reference of const_AnimalFamily to temp. So now whenever you modify temp (from wherever it was passed) you are going to go through same changes in your constant array.

**I would suggest you do something like:**

**You do a deep copy of your temp array rather than changing the reference.**

OR

**when you pass temp array, you pass the cloned (Arrays.copyOf) version of array rather than raw array.**